# Python - Sockets set SO_BROADCAST for one sending

Tags: python, sockets, udp, broadcasting

I have a sender class for sending data using sockets:

```
import socket as s

class Sender:
    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    def send(self, msg, addr):
        self.socket.sendto(msg, addr)
```

And I can create an instance of `Sender` to send data:

```
sender = Sender()
sender.send("Message example", (ip, port))
```

The problem is that the sender might want to send a broadcast to `255.255.255.255`.

Normally for broadcasts I do:

```
self.socket.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
```

The reason this doesn't work here is because my sender might send broadcasts or send messages to ips.

How would I set `SO_BROADCAST` only when a broadcast is sent without making separate sender classes and instances: `Sender`, `BroadcastSender`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if using `s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_DGRAM)` you can't send broadcasting message ! You want low level access  but use high level  class.  `RAW` socket only can send this, other connections(`TCP`/`UDP`) got target(IP/PORT). My offer don't use copy/paste codes, otherwise miss  a lot information. (`RAW` required `root/administrator` permission).

Comment: When I say broadcasting message, I mean sending a message to a broadcast port i.e `255.255.255.255` where others are listening for messages coming from that ip. I've just figured out a solution anyways.

Comment: Why? Setting it doesn't prevent you from unicasting. Just set it on the socket when you open it. Then you can both unicast and broadcast.

Comment: @user207421 Nice, I didn't know that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

As [@user207421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421) said:

> Why? Setting it doesn't prevent you from unicasting. Just set it on
>   the socket when you open it. Then you can both unicast and broadcast.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

To allow your socket to send messages to `255.255.255.255` (broadcast) you can do something like this...

Inside `Sender` class:

```
def send(self, msg, addr):
    if addr[0] == "255.255.255.255": self.socket.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    self.socket.sendto(msg, addr)
    if addr[0] == "255.255.255.255": self.socket.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_BROADCAST, 0)
```